# My Program is getting an error "name lookup of 'a' changed for ISO 'for' scoping "

Tags: c++, error-correction

I' am making program to check holes in the user enter text...Holes are the Character like 'A','B','P' etc...But its getting an error in the loop

I have Posted Complete Code Below..Help to Find the error

```
       #include <iostream>
      #include <cstring>
      #ifdef __cplusplus__
        #include <cstdlib>
      #else
        #include <stdlib.h>
      #endif
      using namespace std;
      int main()
      {
          label:
          cout << "Enter Number of test Case : ";
          int tc;
          cin >> tc;
          int * hls = new int [tc];
          hls = {0};
          if(tc > 40)
          {
              if (system("CLS")) system("clear");
              goto label;
          }
          char *str = new char [tc];
          for(int a = 0; a < tc; ++a)
              {
              cout << "Enter your " << a+1 << "  text : ";
              cin >> str[a];
              }
      for(a = 0; a < tc; ++a) // getting error in this line.
       {
       for(int b = 0; b < strlen(str[a]); ++b)
        {
               switch(str[b])
               {
                   case 'A' :
                   case 'D' :
                   case 'O' :
                   case 'Q' :
                   case 'P' :
                   ++hls[b];
                   break;
                   case  'B' : hls[b] += 2;
                   break;
                   default :
                   break;
               }
           }
         }
     if (system("CLS")) system("clear");
      for(a = 0; a < tc; ++a)
         cout << hls[a] << endl;
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: The code, as you are presenting it, should not compile, as it is semantically wrong.

Comment: Is `str` a string or an array/vector/... of strings?

Comment: Now i have posted Complete code..Please detect why the error is showing.

Answer (score 2):

Your `a` is not declared in the scope of the scope of the second for loop.

`a` only exists within the body of this for loop:

```
for(int a = 0; a < tc; ++a)
{
    cout << "Enter your " << a+1 << "  text : ";
    cin >> str[a];
}
```

Now `a` no longer exists, but you try to use it anyway:

```
for(a = 0; a < tc; ++a) // getting error in this line.
```

(you also try it use it again later)

Either declare `int a;` within the body of `main()` so it remains in scope, or (better) just declare it within each subsequent for loop, like you did in the first one.

There are other problems with the code, but that's the one you asked about. :)

Comment: Thanks its working but gets another on the next line

Comment: Yes, but SO prefers specific questions, not interactive "debug my code" sessions. Your error on the next line is because `str` is a single character array of `tc` characters, but you're trying to index it as if it's an array of arrays. Is there any particular reason you are using C-style strings and memory management? This would be much easier to code using `std::string` and `std::vector`.